# Azure Synapse - Is there a way to import data from an ODBC source in batches?

Tags: azure, odbc, netsuite, azure-synapse

We are attempting to import data from Netsuite into Azure Synapse Analytics via SuiteAnalytics Connect (ODBC) - this works on all but one table (transactionLine) where the connection always times out at 2 hours

From speaking to Oracle it appears the the two hour limit is fixed and cannot be increased.

I have a Copy Data activity set up in a pipeline, when I set "Use Query" to "Table" it times out but when I set it to "Query" and limit it to a small number of rows (e.g. 100) it works fine (see screenshot)

Is there a built in way to import this data in batches, say 1000 rows at a time, without creating dozens of separate Copy Data activities?

[image: Copy data limit to 100 rows]

Comment: Try increasing the Query timeouts value and check

Comment: 1440 minutes is 24 hours (which is the maximum in these copy activities), and it is failing at 2 hours. It's definitely a limitation on the netsuite side so I'm looking for a way to batch, not just to increase the timeout

Comment: what is your sink?

Comment: a dedicated SQL pool

Comment: write batch option in sink copy the data in the batches as you mention [Image](https://i.imgur.com/RY068cl.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your pipeline to work when the large no of records or to create a Batches to import data you can use the following approach.

- If there are large no of records and you want to batch them in 1000 rows first use the lookup activity and the get the count of all records and store it in the set variable with below dynamic expression or if you know the number you and directly add it in set variable activity.

```
#to get ftom lookup
@string(activity('Lookup1').output.count)

#to add manually
@string(5000)
```

[image]

- I took another variable to set the starting of records processed as  `start`.

```
@string(1)
```

[image]

- I took another variable to set the ending of records processed as  `end`.

```
@string(1000)
```

[image]

- Now use  `until`  activity to process until the  `end`  value is greater than  `left`.

```
@greater(variables('end'),variables('left'))
```

[image]

- **Now, use the  `execute pipeline`  activity and pass the variable values to that pipeline parameters and with help of this parameters you can query the data and import it in batches.**

[image]

- Now we have to update the values of  `start`  and  `end`  where we increment the value of  `start`  and and also increment the value of   `end`.
- Since we can't self-reference a variable, we have to take a temporary reference variable and then update it.
- To update the value of  `start`, I have taken as  `changestart`  variable with following value.

```
@string(add(int(variables('start')),1000))
```

[image]

- Assign the above  `changestart`  value to  `start`  variable.

[image]

- Follow similarly for  `end`  as well. The following is a debug output when there are 5000 records.

[image]